# Beta Conversion for Lambda Calculus Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I want to implement a function which does beta reduction to a lambda expression where my lambda expression is of the type:

```
data Expr = App Expr Expr | Abs Int Expr | Var Int deriving (Show,Eq)
```

My evaluation function so far is:

```
eval1cbv :: Expr -> Expr
eval1cbv (Var x) = (Var x)
eval1cbv (Abs x e) = (Abs x e)
eval1cbv (App (Abs x e1) e@(Abs y e2)) = eval1cbv (subst e1 x e)
eval1cbv (App e@(Abs x e1) e2) =  eval1cbv (subst e2 x e)  
eval1cbv (App e1 e2) = (App (eval1cbv e1) e2)
```

where `subst` is a function used to define substitution.

However, when I try to reduce an expression using beta reduction I get a non-exhaustive patterns error and I cannot understand why. What I can do to fix it is adding an extra case at the bottom like this:

```
eval :: Expr -> Expr
eval (Abs x e) = (Abs x e)
eval (App (Abs x e1) e@(Abs y e2)) = subst e1 x e
eval (App e@(Abs x e1) e2) = App e (eval e2)
eval (App e1 e2) = App (eval e1) e2
eval (Var x) = Var x
```

However, if I do that then the lambda expression is not being reduced at all, meaning that the input is the same as the output of the function.

So, if I try to evaluate a simple case like:

eval (App (Abs 2 (Var 2)) (Abs 3 (Var 3)))   it works fine giving ->
Abs 3 (Var 3)

but when I run it for a bigger test case like:

eval (App (Abs 1 (Abs 2 (Var 1))) (Var 3))  i get:

1. non-exhaustive patterns if I use the first function without adding the last case
2. or the exact same expression App (Abs 1 (Abs 2 (Var 1))) (Var 3), which obviously does not get reduced, if I add the last case

Can anyone help me figure this out please? :)

Comment: Have you considered the error might be in your function `subst`? Also don't you need an `eval` after applying `subst`? Also you should provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's `LamExpr`?

Answer (score 2):

> but when I run it for a bigger test case like:
>
> ```
> eval (App (Abs 1 (Abs 2 (Var 1))) (Var 3))
> ```

When you try to apply something of the form `Abs x e` to `Var y`, you're in this branch,

> ```
> eval (App e@(Abs x e1) e2) = App e (eval e2)
> ```

so you have,

> ```
>   App (Abs x e) (Var y)
> = App (Abs x e) (eval (Var y))
> = App (Abs x e) (Var y)
> ```

This is not what you want to do. Both `(Abs x e)` and `(Var y)` are in normal form (i.e. evaluated), so you should have substituted. You appear to only treat lambdas, and not variables, as evaluated.

---

There are more problems with your code. Consider this branch,

> ```
> eval (App e1 e2) = App (eval e1) e2
> ```

The result is always an `App`. E.g. if `eval e1 = Abs x e` then the result is  `App (Abs x e) e2`. It stops there, not further evaluation is performed.

And consider this branch,

> ```
> eval (App (Abs x e1) e@(Abs y e2)) = subst e1 x e
> ```

What happens if the result of substitution is an application term? Will the result be evaluated?

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your changes, given `LamApp e1 e2` you were following a call-by-value evaluation strategy before (i.e. you were evaluating `e2` before substituting). That is gone,

Here it `e2` is a lambda so it needs no evaluation,

> ```
> eval1cbv (LamApp (LamAbs x e1) e@(LamAbs y e2)) = eval1cbv (subst e1 x e)
> ```

Here you substitute anyway regardless of what `e2` is, so you do the exact same as before. You don't need the previous case then and are now following a call-by-name evaluation strategy. I don't know if that's what you want. Also you are calling `subst` with the wrong arguments here. I suppose you mean `subst e1 x e2` and you don't need that `@e`.

> ```
> eval1cbv (LamApp e@(LamAbs x e1) e2) =  eval1cbv (subst e2 x e)
> ```

Here you are just evaluating the first argument which is consistent with a call-by-name strategy. But again I don't know if that's your intention.

> ```
> eval1cbv (LamApp e1 e2) = (LamApp (eval1cbv e1) e2)
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried changing my code to this one above, which manages to reduce it a little bit but not completely. Could you please take a look and let me know of any suggested changes please? :)

Comment: @JoeBowtie edited with some comments on your new version.